# Assigning output from awk to variable

Tags: shell, unix, awk, aix

I have a script whose contents are as below:

```
    result= awk 's=100 END  {print  s }' 
    echo "The result is" $result
```

The desired output is:

```
The result is 100
```

My script is running without exiting and I am also not getting the desired output.
Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to assign the output of a command to a variable.

The syntax is: `var1=$(command)`.

```
result=$(awk 'BEGIN{s=100} END {print s}' /dev/null)
echo "The result is $result"
```

Answer (score 1):

The awk command needs to have some input!

```
awk 's=100 END  {print  s }' <input file here>
```

you need to change your line to:

```
result= `awk 's=100 END  {print  s }' <input file>`
```

the reason why it hangs is that awk is wating for its input!

Comment: Actually my command is 

    result = `awk '/<Main>/ { f=1 } f && /Amt/ { split($0,a,/[<>]/); s+=a[3] } /<\/Main>/ { f=0 } END {print  s }' MyFile.xml`
    echo "The result is " $result


But i am getting oytput as

    result: 0653-690 Cannot open =.
    result: 0653-690 Cannot open 23.
    The result is